# React http-proxy-middleware It works locally but not on the main server

Tags: reactjs, proxy, http-proxy-middleware

I work locally with http-proxy-middeware and there is no problem
After building the project with npm run build
When I transfer the project to the main server, the proxy does not work anymore and gives a 404 error
Thank you for your advice`

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
```

module.exports = function(app) {
app.use(
'/api',
createProxyMiddleware({
target: 'https://backend_api.com',
changeOrigin: true
})
);
};